# How to get method level coverage with gcovr?

Tags: code-coverage, gcov, gcovr

I've been working with gcovr to generate coverage data for my whole project.

I am able to generate summary reports like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: ...../src/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/A/A1/xyz.cpp                            1609       2     0%   97,99,101....
src/A/A2/abcg.cpp                            271       4     1%   .......
src/B/B1/mnop.cpp                             74       2     2%   34,42,56-.....
src/B/B2/wrds.cpp                           1533       6     0%   76,83,85-.....
src/C/C1/abcdefg.cpp                        1079       8     0%   143,150,152.....
```

with total and everything else too, but this data is at source level. So I tried generating xml files which had the same kind of data in xml format. When I finally generated denser xml file with line level coverage like this one:

```
<class branch-rate="0.285714285714" complexity="0.0" filename="src/absc/mno/xyz/ahgs.cpp" line-rate="0.231481481481" name="os_clib_hxx">
<methods/>
<lines>
<line branch="false" hits="0" number="200"/>
<line branch="false" hits="0" number="202"/>
<line branch="false" hits="3" number="208"/>
<line branch="false" hits="3" number="210"/>
<line branch="false" hits="63" number="213"/>
<line branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)" hits="63" number="215">
<conditions>
<condition coverage="50%" number="0" type="jump"/>
</conditions>
</line>
<line branch="false" hits="0" number="218"/>
.........
..........
```

I still couldn't find anything method level.
I know it is possible with gcov to generate method level coverage for one file at a time, but that is not possible in my case as I am working with thousands of files, for which if I try to generate data for each of them by any method it would be problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, gcovr is not currently able to report coverage on a per-function basis.

The XML report contains an empty `<methods/>` section because this section is required by the DTD schema for the Cobertura XML format, but it does not contain useful data. Similarly, other XML fields like `complexity` just contain dummy data.